# how to make input always onFocus

Tags: css, reactjs, input, onblur, onfocus

i have input and i want to always keep it onFocused, even i blur it and click on another parts of page, still stay focused.

first i use this

```
 const inputReference = useRef();
  const[foc,setFoc] = useState();
 
    const focu =() =>{
      const focuss = inputReference.current.onfocus
      setFoc(focuss)

    } 
returrn(
<input ref={inputReference} />
//or
<input type="text" ref={input => input && input.focus()}/>
//or
<input onBlur="focus()" autofocus /> 
//or
<input onBlur={focu} /> 
//or
<input  type='text'  autoFocus={true} onBlur={({ target }) => target.focus()}/>
)
```

none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simple implementation, basically you add event listeners to [mouse-move|click|other] to your parent element

```js
function App () {
  const inputRef = React.createRef()
  
  function handleFocus () {
    inputRef.current.focus()
  }
  
  
  return (
    <div class="container" onClick={handleFocus} onMouseMove={handleFocus}>
      <h4>Mouse move or click will focus input inside this gray block</h4>
      <input placeholder="text" ref={inputRef} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just focus your input when the component is mounted, and then add an onBlur function on your input

```
const focus = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus()
}

useEffect(() => {
    focus()
}, [])
```

And then for the input

```
<input ref={inputRef} onBlur={focus} />
```